# Cmd traceroute not being affected by VPN configuration

Tags: vpn, socks5

I am using a virtual private server in combination with SOCKS5 proxy, which in essence provides the same functionality as VPN.

When I connect and check my public IP, it shows the location of the server. However, when I do a traceroute to a website in cmd, it only goes through local connections in my country.

Is this ok? Is the traffic not supposed to be all routed through the VPS?

Comment: SOCKS5 does not inherently provide any sort of encryption.  You may have enabled such a configuration on your VPS, but that's not the default.  See a few other SE Q&A's http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/719/is-socks-secure and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123419/socks5-is-there-encryption-between-client-and-proxy-server and http://superuser.com/questions/349831/how-to-encrypt-socks5-traffic to get started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application must be specifically support the use of a SOCKS proxy. Web browsers usually do, while most other applications usually do not. There are some ways to ["socksify"](https://www.google.com/search?q=socksify) other applications but details depend on the OS and maybe the application too.

Apart from that SOCKS5 supports only tunneling of TCP and UDP. traceroute and tracert often default to use of ICMP which can not be tunneled with SOCKS5.

Comment: I laughed quite a lot on the word socksify, hearing it for the first time :)
Thanks for the info.. in that case, it makes sense.